# Check if class exists in Java classpath without running its static initializer?

Tags: java, class, classloader

If I use

```
   try {
      Class.forName("my.package.Foo");
      // it exists on the classpath
   } catch(ClassNotFoundException e) {
      // it does not exist on the classpath
   }
```

the static initializer block of "Foo" is kicked off. Is there a way to determine whether a class "my.package.Foo" is on the classpath without kicking off its static initializer?

Answer (score 94, accepted):

Try the `forName(String name, boolean initialize, ClassLoader loader)` method of `Class` and set the param `initialize` to `false`.

[JavaDoc link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName(java.lang.String,%20boolean,%20java.lang.ClassLoader))

Comment: Should work. According to the API: The class is initialized only if the initialize parameter is true and if it has not been initialized earlier.

Comment: The `ClassLoader` parameter should be generally set to `this.getClass().getClassLoader()`?

Comment: you know of all the results I found in a google search, you're the only one who mentions the initialize parameter - seems a big thing to me if one is just testing the existence of a class (he'd not want to usually load it), wonder why the other people didn't bother to mention it.

Comment: Contrary to @aliteralmind Java itself [sets](https://zgrepcode.com/java/openjdk/10.0.2/java.base/java/lang/class.java#L-287) this parameter to ` Reflection.getCallerClass()`

Comment: example call ??

Answer (score 1):

Since Java 9 there is a new Method that checks if the class exists but without throwing an exception in case the class does not exist this should be prefered instead of an expected exception.

For example this function checks the existence of a class when given the package and class name:

```java
/**
 * Checks if a class can be found with the classloader.
 * @param moduleName a Module.
 * @param className the binary name of the class in question.
 * @return true if the class can be found, otherwise false.
 */
private boolean classExists(String moduleName, String className) {
    Optional<Module> module = ModuleLayer.boot().findModule(moduleName);
    if(module.isPresent()) {
        return Class.forName(module.get(), className) != null;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Bonus: Additional function that does only take one parameter

```java
/**
 * Checks if a class can be found with the classloader.
 * @param name the fully qualified name of the class in question.
 * @return true if the class can be found, otherwise false.
 */
private boolean classExists(String name) {
    int lastDot = name.lastIndexOf('.');
    String moduleName = name.substring(0, lastDot);
    String className = name.substring(lastDot+1);
    return classExists(moduleName, className);
}
```

Link: [related JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName-java.lang.Module-java.lang.String-)