# how to get details of 3rd party jar`s present in project programmatically android

Tags: android

I am eager to know that is it possible to get details of jars present in an Android project programmatically. 
I have searched on Google, but couldn't find any blog or information related to this. Is this possible?

Comment: details of jar. file? where (pc, android), when (dev time,  run time)?

Comment: in android project  and at run time

Comment: at run time there are no jars in built apk, so you cant do that

Comment: are you sure because....sometimes we get NoClassDefFoundError ..when class is not found

Comment: usually we import JAR files in project

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking specifically to see if a class is accessible, you could check directly to see if the class exists. Refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3466568/346232)

If you're looking more for a list, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1429172/346232) might help you.

Comment: actually i want to know the jar details and list of jars present in project , is this possible ?

Comment: do you specifically want to do it in Java from within the project, or would you like to just see a list so you can, for example, identify orphaned JARs? If the latter, http://classpathhelper.sourceforge.net/ would work.

Comment: yes exactly .... i want to know list of used and orphaned JARs...ok try your link