# JDBC catching login failure exception and re-promts for input

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

```
try{
Class.forName ("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"); // identify

Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection
 ("jdbc:oracle...",userid,password); 


// create Statement and execute sql statement after
} catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Transcript.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

The only exception I can find is SQLException, but how can it distinguish from login failure and incorrect sql statement?

I want it to re-promts the user for another chance of entering id and password, do I put that in the catch block?

if so, do i need another nested try-catch to handle the exception?

As I want to handle the two situations separately, but it seems like there is only a SQLException I can use.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3466568/check-if-class-exists-in-java-classpath-without-running-its-static-initializer

Comment: Extract those two operations (acquiring the connection and executing SQL statements) into their own methods, each of which can have separate try-catch blocks for exception handling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, you'll get a few more:

```
If you don't have the right Oracle driver in the classpath in Class.forName:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver

If DriverManager.getConnection fails because of a wrong jdbc url syntax:
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:oracle...

If login/password fails at DriverManager.getConnection
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied

In case of an incorrect SQL statement:
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

In case of an incorrect SQL statement:
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement

In case of an incorrect SQL statement:
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column name
```

You can separate the login failure from SQL failures because they happen at different place in your code.

```
public class Oracle {

    public static void main(final String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        final Connection con;

        try {
            Class.forName ("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"); 
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Driver failure");
        }

        try {
            con = DriverManager.getConnection ("jdbc:oracle:thin:schema/password@host:port:sid");
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Login failure");
        }


        try {
            final Statement stmt = con.createStatement();

            final String sql = "select 1 from dual";
            final ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
            while(rs.next()) {
                // do something with the data
            }
            rs.close();
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("SQL failure");
        }
    }
}
```

Note: it is a brute-force example, in a production code you may need more precise exception handlers, and you shall ensure that resources are always closed. For example, in case of an SQL error while reading a resut set and having an error because of referring to an invalid column, you may need to close the statement as well as the result set.

Two more Oracle-specific hints:

- Do not pass login and password as a param in DriverManager.getConnection. An Oracle connection has a lot more parameters, it is easier to construct a JDBC url which contains everything: "jdbc:oracle:thin:schema/password@host:port:sid"

  - Note that host:port is needed. Many times multiple Oracle server instances can share the same port. You can use the service id (SID) to distinguish amongst them.
- In case of a real Oracle exception, the exception is wrapped to an SQLException or an SQLSyntaxErrorException, sometimes this, sometimes that. I found pretty handy to put an own logic on top of this:

  - I catch any exception with try..catch. If the error message starts with ORA-, then it is an Oracle error, and I wrap it to a custom exception class and re-throw.
  - It might be handly to parse the Oracle error code in your custom exception. You can use that to differentiate between custom Oracle exceptions (-20000..-20999) what you throw in your PL/SQL (and can signal business level error). The rest of error codes always tell a technical error, i.e. something is wrong in your code or in the database structure.

To close a resource (pre-java7), use try..finally. Note the pessimistic handling of possible further exceptions when actually closing a resouce fails.

```
Statement stmt=null;
ResultSet rs=null;
try {
    try {
        final Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        final String sql = "select 1 from dual";
        rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
        while(rs.next()) {
            // do something with the data
        }
        rs.close();
        rs=null;
        stmt.close();
        stmt=null;
    } catch (final Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("SQL failure");
    }
} finally {
    if (rs!=null) {
        try {
            rs.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // ignore - we can't do too much
        }
    }
    if (stmt!=null) {
        try {
            stmt.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // ignore - we can't do too much
        }
    }
}
```

To close the resources on Java7 and above, you can benefit of the **try with resource** block. See [How should I use try-with-resources with JDBC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8066501/how-should-i-use-try-with-resources-with-jdbc)

Comment: Thank you so much! May I ask where I close my resources? I usually just put them at the end, but If the program crashes at some point and doesn't reach the close() statements, will that be a big problem?

Comment: When the program crashes, the operating system will close all resources, so no worry on that.

However, if in your program you run 1001 select statements, and you never close the statements and the result sets, that is more a problem. Oracle has a limited number of cursors you can keep open, and each open result set uses one. Not closing resources can therefore make your program throwing errors after some time of use.

Comment: I see! Thank you so much for your explanation! :)